# Override types for all module's exports

Tags: javascript, typescript

I'm building a UI library and now I have this:

```js
export * from 'npm-module'
```

`npm-module` has the following declaration

```js
export declare const constA: string;
export declare const constB: string;
export declare const constC: string;
// ...
```

I would like to override the type for all the imports from `npm-module`, something like this:

```js
type MyType = string

export * as MyType from 'npm-module'  // not real code, just an idea
```

My aim is to ensure that users will use only imported const from this module for a specific component.

Is there a way to achieve it? I guess it is something I can do with a declaration file.

Answer (score 1):

> My aim is to ensure that users will use only imported const from this module for a specific component.

In that case, here's an alternative solution for you: Use a string enum, and have your component only accept that string enum's values. A string enum value can be used where a string is expected, but not vice-versa.

Here's a rough sketch:

```
import { TheLibraryComponent } from "npm-module";

export enum MyType {
    THIS = "this",
    THAT = "that",
    THE_OTHER = "the other",
}

export interface MyComponentProps {
    relevantProp: MyType;
}

export const MyComponent = ({relevantProp}: MyComponentProps) => {
    return (
        {/*...*/}
        <TheLibraryComponent relevantProp={relevantProp} />
        {/*...*/}
    );
};
```

---

But if you wanted to do it the way you described, there'd be two parts:

1. Making the type not just an alias for `string`.
2. Updating the types of the exports.

Looking at #1, `type MyType = string;` won't do much for you because in TypeScript's structural type system, `MyType` and `string` are the exact same thing; the type system is based on the shapes of types (structural), not the names/identities of types (nominal).

You could solve that by using a branded type, like `type MyType = string & {__type__: "MyType" };`. You can never actually have a value of that type (because `string` is primitive), but you can use type assertions to make TypeScript think strings are `MyType`s.

Then for #2, you'll need to import and re-export the constants individually (as far as I know, you can't do them en masse). Sketch:

```
import * as lib from "npm-module";
import { LibraryComponent } from "npm-module";

type MyType = string & {__type__: "MyType" };

export const constA = lib.constA as MyType;
export const constB = lib.constB as MyType;
export const constC = lib.constC as MyType;

export interface MyComponentProps {
    relevantProp: MyType;
}

export const MyComponent = ({relevantProp}: MyComponentProps) => {
    return (
        {/*...*/}
        <TheLibraryComponent relevantProp={relevantProp} />
        {/*...*/}
    );
};
```

But I'd probably use the enum.

Comment: Thanks. As you said I can't re-export the constants individually, it's an icon library and there are hundreds of icons, and I want to keep them updated automatically. Sorry but I don't understand why in the first solution you import `TheLibraryComponent` from 'npm-module'. I also don't understand what enum should contain. FYI: i'm using vuejs.

Comment: @Fab - I don't think you get much choice about re-exporting, you can't do them en masse as I said. You might want to rethink your approach of trying to change their type. Re `TheLibraryComponent`: I assumed you were using a component from `npm-module` in your component, so I included that for context. Sorry if I got that wrong.